# The .aspx extension is cut when redirecting between pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a web application using web forms. I encountered an error during redirecting between pages. I'm using `Response.Redirect("~/Logout.aspx")` which is not working. I noticed, that the extension is missing in browser so in browser there is a http://localhost/mywebapp/Logout instead of http://localhost/mywebapp/Logout.aspx.
But when I change the redirect function to `Response.Redirect("~/Logout.aspx/")` so I add one slash to the end of the relative url then it is working properly. I can not find out why this behavior is. I do not think that it should work like this.
the complete code is really short:

```
try{
   var provider = GetCurrentAuthProvider();
   provider.RefreshToken();
}
catch(InvalidTokenException e)
{
   Response.Redirect("~/Logout.aspx");
}
```

Did someone have similar issue?

Comment: Do you have friendly URLS or URL rewriting etc in your app?

Comment: No they are not enabled.